# find points in an area around an identified point

Tags: algorithm, mobile, location

I want to make an mobile app based on location with many users. An user wants to quickly find all other users in a distance(ex: 10km) around him, the distance doesn't need to be too exact(maybe from 9km to 11km instead of 10km), server will handle this process. If I have milions of users so Brute force will mean doing too many calculations. Can you suggest me some other solutions or algorithms?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you can do:

Divide the entire area into a pseudo-grid. Your app updates the server with its location denoting the tile number whenever a user moves from one tile to another tile. This can be done usually using the `GPS` AFAIK.

So, the server continuously keeps track of the current tile in which the mobile is residing. Now, when a user asks for nearby neighbors, its a matter of seconds, since the sever only need to send the list of users in the tiles adjacent to the current user's tile.

Also, note that you need to choose the tile size based on the distance till which you wanted to scan for nearby users.

Comment: Oh, I also had the same Idea like you and Laune, I think I'll use this solution.
Thanks!

Comment: you can accept/upvote if you find any answer useful.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd keep a Map<Area,Set<User>> where Area is some expression derived from a User's coordinates. As a simple case, use a function with degrees N/S and E/W. If a user wants to locate close buddies, you'll have to retrieve the users from that Area and (possibly) from one, two or three adjoining areas.

There are 360*180 = 64800 pairs <deg,deg> but far more than (guess, guess) 90% will not be used at all. You can extend this to pairs <deg.min, deg.min>, i.e., 360*180*3600 = 233280000 different pairs, with the same percentage of non-usage.

Comment: Thanks!
Sorry because I don't have enough reputation to vote up